# ¿Cómo hago para que el formulario se cierre por completo? C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios, c#-8.0

Tengo una aplicación en c# de logueo y un panel principal, pero cuando cierro el formulario el formulario no se cierra por completo, este el código que tengo en el evento FormClosing:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si solo ejecuto el formulario del panel principal este código funciona y cierra el formulario por completo pero si ejecuto todo el proyecto con el logueo, no funciona y el programa queda en segundo plano.

Agradecería su Ayuda :)

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara, podrias dar mas detalles o explicarte un pocomejor?

Comment: Hola, si pones el código en formato texto los usuarios te podran ayudar mejor

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: ¿Y cerrar la ventana con un `this.Close();`?

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de probar verificando las dos posibles respuestas con un `else if` en vez de solo con un `else`, entonces quedaría algo así:

```
private void Principal_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult resultado = MessageBox.Show("¿Seguro Que Desea Cerrar el Programa?", "Salir", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (resultado == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else if (resultado == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

No dudes en comunicarnos si funcionó, y la próxima vez intenta compartir el código directamente.

Comment: pòdrias explicar porque usando un else if se solucionaria el problema? DialogResult puede tomar otro valor? que pasa si toma otro valor? e.cancel en que queda?